# Hibernate query.list() is slower than HibernateTemplate.find()

Tags: spring, hibernate

We upgraded our project from Spring 3x/Hibernate 3x to Spring 4.1.5/Hibernate 4.3.8.

Initially we were using Hibernate Tempate. During upgrade we removed the Hibernate Template of spring and used Spring's declarative transaction management.

Earlier our query with **hibernateTemplate** used to take very sort time to retrive 3500 records from DB. Now when are using **query.list()**, the running time is coming in minutes (4-5 mins approx).

**Old Code**

```
DAO Class:
---------
public List<LatestRecVO> getListRecs(String listId) {
    HibernateTemplate ht = new HibernateTemplate(getSessionFactory());  
    List<LatestRecVO> listOfRecs = ht.find(" from LatestRecVO a where a.listId = ? order by a.listRecId asc", Long.valueOf(listId) );
    return listOfRecs;
}

Service Class:
--------------
@Transactional
public List<LatestRecVO> getListRecs(String listId) {
    List<LatestRecVO> listOfRecs = listDao.getListRecDetails(listId); 
    return listOfRecs;
}
```

**New Code**

```
DAO Class:
---------
public List<LatestRecVO> getListRecs(String listId) {
    Query q = getSession().createQuery(" from LatestRecVO a where a.listId = (:listId) order by a.listRecId asc");  
    q.setParameter("listId", Long.valueOf(listId));
    List<LatestRecVO> listOfRecs = q.list();
    return listOfRecs;
}

Service Class:
--------------
@Transactional
public List<LatestRecVO> getListRecs(String listId) {
    List<LatestRecVO> listOfRecs = listDao.getListRecDetails(listId); 
    return listOfRecs;
}
```

The entity class **LatestRecVO** do not have any associated entity with it.

I checked the Hibernate Template's find() method and saw its uses some caching.

Tried 2nd level cache along with query cache but it didnt helped. I may have configured 2nd level cache incorrectly but to try it again i want to be sure that its the way out else i would be wasting time.

I made show_sql as true and can see it just ran a singly query. On DB the same query takes some milliseconds to run. It seems like hibernate is taking time to build objects from the result.

On one of the post it was mentioned that its mandate to have a default constructor in our entities. I have not created any constructor in my entity class so i assume that i do have java's default constructor in place.

My table has 36 columns and in total there are 4k records to be fetched.

Any pointer in this will be really helpful.

**Update**

Sorry, I cannot post the complete code here, so just giving the details. I have the composite primary key for LatestRecVO. I have created a class **LatestRecPK** for primary key, it implements **serializable** and have **@Embeddable** annotation. In LatestRecVO i have given **@IdClass(LatestRecPK.class)** to include the primary key class.  **LatestRecVO** has a CLOB property along with String, Long and @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) properties and corresponding setters/getters.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609645/simple-hibernate-query-returning-very-slowly

Comment: Even knowing that LatestRecVO do not have any associated entity with it, can we see its code?

Comment: Marcelo, LatestRecVO do not have any association with it, I can confirm on that. I checked that link, adding a argument constructor didn't helped us out. 

I increased the hibernate logging level and could just see a singly query. I can see the Query in logs as soon as the method was hit but coming out of method takes lot of time. Seems like hibernate is taking lot of time to construct objects. 

We ran the same query with plain JDBC, iterated resultset and formed objects in while loop. JDBC too took some 3 minutes for creating all 4k objects and adding them to a list.