# Spring Data Jpa query resultset to object creation is very slow

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a domain object,defined as :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_domin")
@Builder
public class Domain {

  @Column(name = "BUSINESS_DATE")
  private LocalDateTime businessDate;

  @Column(name = "DATA_PROVIDER")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private DataProvider dataProvider;

}
```

For the above domain Object I've Spring Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface DomainRepository extends JpaRepository<Domain, UUID> {

  List<Domain> findByBusinessDate(LocalDateTime businessDate);
}
```

when I'm querying :
repository.findByBusinessDate(someDate) --> I get 1000 records in more than a minute,where as same query if I run on db(oracle) I get the result-set within a sec.

I turned on the log (TRACE) ,I see that its taking more time in extracting the result set into list of java object:

```
TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor
```

How can i tune the performance ?

Comment: Does the SQL sent to the database by the Hibernate is **exactly** the query that you run on db? No only the SQL, [but the parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27727591/2387977). Also, try to remove all `Lombok` annotations only to isolate the real cause. Show us the version of Hibernate are you using too, because the LocalDateTime is not [fully supported](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/) in some versions.

Comment: Yes,I ran the same query on db which is generated by Hibernate.I'm Using Hibernate 5.2. I don't think lombok is causing side effect on performence

Comment: My main concern is the `@AllArgsConstructor`. Try to remove it and test again.

Comment: @AllArgsConstructor is required when Builder is used with NoArgsConstructor

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate default fetch size is 10 ,which was causing the issue .
For large result sets, it’s important to increase the fetch size,so by changing the fetch size at query level its become really faster.

```
@QueryHints(@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.fetchSize", value = "1000"))
List<Domain> findByBusinessDate(LocalDateTime businessDate);
```

If you want it globally add this in your property file:

```
hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size:1000
```