# Java application processing slow while hosted in godaddy

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-mvc, networking

We are using application with hibernate 4.0.0, spring 4.2.4 ,  server Apache tomcat 7, JDK 1.7 & JRE 1.7 , database SQL. Application works fine in local but when hosted it takes much time to render the page. Hosting environment is dedicated.
Kindly give some suggestion to get rid of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the same thing can work properly on your development machine then it should work the same on the hosting machine. The major problems can be:

1. You are using a shared environment.
2. CPU and RAM resources allowed to your application, are low.
3. Network bandwidth is lower than you wanted.
4. Server may be expecting a bit of problem itself.

I would recommend communicating with the GoDaddy officials to get help in this matter.

Comment: Hi man, 1).we are not using a shared environment , 2) 32 gb ram using  ,3).let i check about the bandwidth, 4)how could we conclude about the server prblm

Comment: actually sql query response works fine , hibernate query related pages not working fine after host

Comment: then this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609645/simple-hibernate-query-returning-very-slowly may help you